# How do I prove the existence of a set of finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, Prove that then for every $\epsilon >0$,

i) There exists a set of finite measure $B$ such that $\int_{B^c} |f(x)|dx< \epsilon.$

ii) There is a $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{E} |f(x)|dx< \epsilon$, where $m(E)<\delta$.

In this question, I proved that if $f \in L^1$, then the set $\{x: f(x)\neq0\}$ is sigma finite.

Can anyone suggest me me how do I prove the existence of the set $B$?

Comment: For $i)$ look at $f_n:=|f|\chi_{|f|\le n}$ and show that $f_n\to |f|$ almost surely and use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to find $n$ such that $\int |f|-\int f_n <\epsilon.$ Can you now see what set $B$ to choose?

Comment: And, for $ii)$ first obtain $n$ from $i)$ such that $\int |f|-\int f_n\le \epsilon/2.$ Now choose $\delta=\epsilon/2n.$ Show that conclusion holds for any $E$ with $m(E)<\delta.$

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\int_\mathbb R |f(x)| dx$ is finite. You also know that the sequence $\int_{[-n,n]} |f(x)| dx$ is monotonic increasing and has limit equal to $\int_\mathbb R |f(x)| dx$. Therefore, for some $n$ it follows that
$$\int_{(-\infty,-n) \cup (n,\infty)} |f(x)| dx = \int_\mathbb R |f(x)| dx - \int_{[-n,n]} |f(x)| dx < \epsilon
$$
Now take $B = [-n,+n]$.

Answer (score 0):

- For the first question, according to Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT), $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_{B(0,n)}|f|=\int_{\mathbb R}|f|,$$
  where $B(0,n)$ is the ball centered at $0$ and of radius $n$.
- For the second one, for all $k>0$,
  $$\int_{E}|f|=\int_{E}|f|\boldsymbol 1_{\{|f|\leq k\}}+\int_{E}|f|\boldsymbol 1_{\{|f|>k\}}.$$

According to MCT, There is $k$ big enough s.t. $$\int_{E}|f|\boldsymbol 1_{\{|f|>k\}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}. $$

Moreover, $$\int_{E}|f|\boldsymbol 1_{\{|f|\leq k\}}\leq km(E\cap\{|f|\leq k\})\leq km(E).$$

Taking $0<\delta <\frac{\varepsilon }{2k}$ yields $$\int_{E}|f|\boldsymbol 1_{\{|f|\leq k\}}\leq \frac{\varepsilon }{2},$$
whenever $m(E)<\delta $. The claim follow.

Answer (score 0):

For (i):

Define
$$B_n=\{ x:|x|\le n \mbox{, } |f(x)|\le n \}  \mbox{, so that } B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq\mbox{... , and } \cup_{n=1}^{+\infty}B_n=\mathbb{R}.$$
Define then the sequence $f_n=\chi_{B_n}f$, we have that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise and $|f_n|\le |f|\in \textit{L}^1$, so that $f_n \rightarrow f \in \textit{L}^1$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$ by the DTC. Now it suffices to choose $n_{\epsilon}$ so that $$\int_{B_{n_{\epsilon}}^C}|f|dm=\int_{B_{n_{\epsilon}}^C}|f-f_{n_{\epsilon}}|dm=||f-f_{n_{\epsilon}}||_{\textit{L}^p}<\epsilon$$ since $f_{n_{\epsilon}}=0$ on $B_{n_{\epsilon}}$.
Also $B_{n_{\epsilon}}$ is limited for its definition at the beginning.

For (ii):

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $A$ be a set such that $\int_{A_C}|f|dm <\epsilon /2$, which i can for the part (i), we also know that f is bounded on A for how we defined $A=B_{n_0}:=\{ x:|x|\le n \mbox{, } |f(x)|\le n \}$. Let $M:=\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|$, and choose $\delta =\epsilon/ (2M)$. Then if F is a measurable set such that $m(F)<\delta $ we obtain
$$\int_F|f|dm=\int_{f\cap A^C}|f|dm + \int_{F\cap A}|f|dm \le \int_{A^C}|f|dm + M\int_{F\cap A}dm \le$$
$$< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + Mm(F)\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}+M\frac{\epsilon}{2M}=\epsilon.$$